# How to add value of missing object after comparing to another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I have an array of months (`var months`), and I am trying to filter out and get the months that the array of object (`var array1`) does not have and add empty value of property `Avg`

```
var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
 "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

var array1 = [{Month: 'Jan', Avg: 10},{Month: 'Feb', Avg: 20},
{Month: 'May', Avg: 50},{Month: 'Jun', Avg: 60}];`
```

Eg. `array1` has the property value of `Month:` `Jan`, `Feb`, `May` and `Jun`, but I want to get the months that are missing and add value of 0 to property `Avg` like `{Month: 'Mar', Avg: 0}, {Month: 'Apr', Avg: 0}, ...` for the missing months comparing it with `months` array

Expected result of array1:

```
[{Month: 'Jan', Avg: 10}, {Month: 'Feb', Avg: 20}, 
{Month: 'Mar', Avg: 0}, {Month: 'Apr', Avg: 0}, 
{Month: 'May', Avg: 50}, {Month: 'Jun', Avg: 60}, 
{Month: 'Jul', Avg: 0}, {Month: 'Aug', Avg: 0},
{Month: 'Sep', Avg: 0}, {Month: 'Oct', Avg: 0}, 
{Month: 'Nov', Avg: 0}, {Month: 'Dec', Avg: 0}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array.map` with `Array.find`

```js
const months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
 "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
const array1 = [{Month: 'Jan', Avg: 10},{Month: 'Feb', Avg: 20},
{Month: 'May', Avg: 50},{Month: 'Jun', Avg: 60}];

const result = months.map(m => array1.find(a => a.Month === m)??{Month: m, Avg: 0});

console.log(result);
```

Reference: [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), [Nullish](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

Comment: Thank you for your response @ProGu! Appreciate your help, and it worked on my program. But I am a Javascript beginner, how can I turn the functions back to traditional call back function and the double question marks in order for me to understand?

Comment: @JACK added reference links to array and nullish coalescing operator

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work pretty much!

```js
var months = [
  "Jan",
  "Feb",
  "Mar",
  "Apr",
  "May",
  "Jun",
  "Jul",
  "Aug",
  "Sep",
  "Oct",
  "Nov",
  "Dec",
];

var array1 = [{
    Month: "Jan",
    Avg: 10
  },
  {
    Month: "Feb",
    Avg: 20
  },
  {
    Month: "May",
    Avg: 50
  },
  {
    Month: "Jun",
    Avg: 60
  },
];

let finalArr = [];

months.filter((e) => {
  let index = array1.findIndex((ele) => ele.Month == e);
  if (index >= 0) {
    finalArr.push(array1[index]);
  } else {
    finalArr.push({
      Month: e,
      Avg: 0
    });
  }
});

console.log(finalArr);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @AkshayBalwani! The result of finalArr of all months is Avg: 0